# Convert an Observable to Single rx java

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I am working with the next code:

```
override fun getSportList(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Single<SportsResponse> {
        return scribeService.getNavMenuItems(dCSServiceContext).map { navMenu ->
            SportsResponse(navMenu as NavMenu)
        }
    }
```

And the getNavMenuItems looks like this:

```
override fun getNavMenuItems(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Observable<NavItem> {
        return getItems(getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext), dCSServiceContext)
    }
```

The thing is that, I have to transform this Observable to a Single, I had used the toSingle() method, just like this:

```
override fun getSportList(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Single<SportsResponse> {
        return scribeService.getNavMenuItems(dCSServiceContext).toSingle().map { navMenu ->
            SportsResponse(navMenu as NavMenu)
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the next error:

Observable emitted too many elements,because the Observable emits more than one element. Similarly expect "Observable emitted no items" if Observable is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the `take(1)` operator to limit the number of emitted items. It doesn't help, though, if no items are emitted.

Comment: As @BobDalgleish mentioned `take(1)` - or `first()` require at least 1 element . You have a couple options RxJava1 `Observable::firstOrDefault` or if you're using RxJava2 (if not why not) you can use `Observable::firstElement()` which returns a `Maybe`.  To me if you can return no elements then `Maybe` is more declarative.

Comment: Yes it solved the problem, but the issue now is that I am not receiving all the items, just the first one.